# delete duplicate rows mysql not unique

Tags: mysql

I have a little problem with database, charge the regisrtos from xls and can load more than two vcese the same xls generating duplicate records, I can not restrict that are unique because they are records that are repeated in several columns ... I meuestro them

```
 id|    Fecha  | EquipoA   | EquipoB | Categoria | Cancha   | Hora  | Nr_J1 | Nombre_J1 | Apellido_J1 | Nr_J2 | Nombre_J2 | Apellido_J2
 1 |Sáb 09 Abr | San Juan  | Edu     | sub18     | San Juan | 15:00 | 39    | A.        | Aunchayna   | 95    | S.        | Villizio 
 2 |Sáb 09 Abr | San Juan  | Impulso | sub16     | San Juan | 16:30 | 39    | A.        | Aunchayna   | 95    | S.        | Villizio 
 3 |Sáb 09 Abr | San Juan A| ISASA   | sub16     | San Juan | 18:00 | 39    | A.        | Aunchayna   | 95    | S.        | Villizio 
 4 |Sáb 09 Abr | San Juan  | ISASA   | sub14     | San Juan | 19:30 | 39    | A.        | Aunchayna   | 95    | S.        | Villizio 
 5 |Sáb 09 Abr | San Juan  | Edu     | sub18     | San Juan | 15:00 | 39    | A.        | Aunchayna   | 95    | S.        | Villizio
```

this is an example register 1 is equal to 5
in all columns, but others differ in EquipoA or EquipoB or Hora...
so I can not make them be unique

I need to clear the log is repeated in this case 5 and leave 1
I'm no expert in MySql and I was very difficult to find the right query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will delete exact duplicates (except of `id` column):

```sql
delete t1
from Table1 t1
join Table1 t2 using (
  `Fecha`,
  `EquipoA`,
  `EquipoB`,
  `Categoria`,
  `Cancha`,
  `Hora`,
  `Nr_J1`,
  `Nombre_J1`,
  `Apellido_J1`,
  `Nr_J2`,
  `Nombre_J2`,
  `Apellido_J2`
)
where t1.id > t2.id
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d33bc/1)

Comment: `t1` and `t2` are both table aliases of your table. I don't know the name of your table so called it `Table1`. You need to replace it with the correct table name.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like all you need is SELECT DISTINCT:

```
SELECT DISTINCT <all columns except id separated by comma> FROM <table name>
```

Comment: I also find duplicate ?, but not how to eliminate

Answer (score 0):

its easy to remove all duplication. you can add a unique INDEX with **IGNORE** on all fields that must be different like this:

```
ALTER IGNORE TABLE yourTable
 ADD UNIQUE KEY idx_dup 
 ( Fecha, EquipoA, EquipoB, Categoria, Cancha, Hora, 
 Nr_J1, Nombre_J1, Apellido_J1, Nr_J2, Nombre_J2, Apellido_J);
```

Save your table first.

**sample**

```
MariaDB [your_schema]> select * from orders;
+----------+------------+-------------+-----------+---------+
| order_id | order_date | order_total | client_id | ship_id |
+----------+------------+-------------+-----------+---------+
|        1 | 2016-03-12 |       10.00 |         1 |       1 |
|        2 | 2016-03-14 |       20.00 |         1 |       2 |
|        3 | 2016-04-13 |       30.00 |         1 |       2 |
|        9 | 2016-05-20 |       10.00 |         2 |       1 |
|       10 | 2016-06-03 |       20.00 |         2 |       2 |
|       11 | 2016-03-12 |       10.00 |         1 |       1 |
+----------+------------+-------------+-----------+---------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [your_schema]> ALTER IGNORE TABLE orders ADD UNIQUE KEY dup (order_date,order_total,client_id,ship_id);
Query OK, 6 rows affected (0.29 sec)
Records: 6  Duplicates: 1  Warnings: 0

MariaDB [your_schema]> select * from orders;
+----------+------------+-------------+-----------+---------+
| order_id | order_date | order_total | client_id | ship_id |
+----------+------------+-------------+-----------+---------+
|        1 | 2016-03-12 |       10.00 |         1 |       1 |
|        2 | 2016-03-14 |       20.00 |         1 |       2 |
|        3 | 2016-04-13 |       30.00 |         1 |       2 |
|        9 | 2016-05-20 |       10.00 |         2 |       1 |
|       10 | 2016-06-03 |       20.00 |         2 |       2 |
+----------+------------+-------------+-----------+---------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [your_schema]>
```